# Remove Date and append from File name in Linux before .CSV

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Hi I have a file name like this. I would like to remove the date part from the file name daily before my load and append the date after the load gets completed. How would I be able to achieve that?.

file name:-

`zip_cost_03_08_2018 21_13_04.csv`

I need the file name like below before my load starts

`zip_cost.csv`

I need to append the date back once my load gets completed.

`zip_cost_03_08_2018 21_13_04.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the timestamp in the format you want by using the `date` command.

```
$ date "+%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S"
03_09_2018_09_21_40
```

So with that, you can just do -

```
mv "zip_cost_03_08_2018 21_13_04.csv" zip_cost.csv
# Run the load operation
mv zip_cost.csv "zip_cost_$(date '+%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S').csv"
```